# Prestashop How override backoffice templates in my own module

Tags: module, overriding, prestashop

if I want to do override admin templates in my own module, for example

```
"modules/{my_module}/override/controllers/admin/templates/products/combinations.tpl"
```

I don't see any changes.

I think this don't work automaticaly. What I should do more?

Answer (score 1):

In prestashop 1.6 you have to manually put it in override folder so for your template it would be

```
override/controllers/admin/templates/products/combinations.tpl
```